# Hyperledger Caliper : Error: No valid responses from any peers when connected to remote fabric server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-caliper

I have setup a Hyperledger fabric node (with 3 organizations each having a single peer) on one remote server and a Hyperledger Caliper node to benchmark it using the sample chaincode (asset-transfer-basic). The same benchmark works locally. but when I change the URLs in the network config files and add SANs in certificate generation it fails:

giving the following error in the worker iterations:

`error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors: +0000 debug [worker-message-handler] Handled "test" message for Worker (24258) error [connectors/v2/FabricGateway] Failed to perform submit transaction [DeleteAsset] using arguments [2_1],  with error: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors: at newEndorsementError (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:49:12) at getResponsePayload (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:17:23) at Transaction.submit (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:212:28) at async V2FabricGateway._submitOrEvaluateTransaction (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-fabric/lib/connector-versions/v2/FabricGateway.js:376:26) at async V2FabricGateway._sendSingleRequest (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-fabric/lib/connector-versions/v2/FabricGateway.js:170:16) at async V2FabricGateway.sendRequests (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/common/core/connector-base.js:78:28) at async MyWorkload.cleanupWorkloadModule (/home/ubuntu/caliper/workload/readAsset.js:52:13) at async CaliperWorker.executeRound (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/worker/caliper-worker.js:214:13) at async WorkerMessageHandler._handleTestMessage (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/worker/worker-message-handler.js:235:22) at async ProcessMessenger.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/caliper/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/worker/worker-message-handler.js:93:13)`

The debug logs at the remote server also show there was a successful TLS handshake:

` DEBU [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake completed in 10.515647ms server=PeerServer remoteaddress=18.216.197.203:39598
DEBU [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake completed in 12.640673ms server=PeerServer remoteaddress=18.216.197.203:39620
DEBU [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake completed in 18.734087ms server=PeerServer remoteaddress=18.216.197.203:39610
DEBU [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake completed in 17.251823ms server=PeerServer remoteaddress=18.216.197.203:39626
DEBU [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake completed in 9.189911ms server=PeerServer remoteaddress=18.216.197.203:39628

Since it was for testing I manually imported the necessary certificate files to the host of caliper and there were no errors in incorrect path.
The networkconfig file:

```
name: Caliper test
version: "2.0.0"

caliper:
  blockchain: fabric
  sutOptions:
    mutualTls: true

channels:
  - channelName: mychannel
    contracts:
      - id: basic

organizations:
  - mspid: Org1MSP
    identities:
      certificates:
        - name: "User1"
          clientPrivateKey:
            path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
          clientSignedCert:
            path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/User1@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
    connectionProfile:
      path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.yaml"
      discover: false
  - mspid: Org2MSP
    identities:
      certificates:
        - name: "User1"
          clientPrivateKey:
            path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/User1@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
          clientSignedCert:
            path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/User1@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/User1@org2.example.com-cert.pem"
    connectionProfile:
      path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/connection-org2.yaml"
      discover: false
  - mspid: Org3MSP
    identities:
      certificates:
        - name: "User1"
          clientPrivateKey:
            path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/User1@org3.example.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
          clientSignedCert:
            path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/User1@org3.example.com/msp/signcerts/User1@org3.example.com-cert.pem"
    connectionProfile:
      path: "network-profiles/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/connection-org3.yaml"
      discover: false
```

`

Tried GRPCing the HF network using peer command and it worked:

```
eer chaincode query -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"Args":["GetAllAssets"]}'
[{"AppraisedValue":300,"Color":"blue","ID":"asset1","Owner":"Tomoko","Size":5,"docType":"asset"},{"AppraisedValue":400,"Color":"red","ID":"asset2","Owner":"Brad","Size":5,"docType":"asset"},{"AppraisedValue":500,"Color":"green","ID":"asset3","Owner":"Jin Soo","Size":10,"docType":"asset"},{"AppraisedValue":600,"Color":"yellow","ID":"asset4","Owner":"Max","Size":10,"docType":"asset"},{"AppraisedValue":700,"Color":"black","ID":"asset5","Owner":"Adriana","Size":15,"docType":"asset"},{"AppraisedValue":800,"Color":"white","ID":"asset6","Owner":"Michel","Size":15,"docType":"asset"}]
```

Comment: This isn't a connectivity issue, the fabric-node-sdk used by caliper made an endorsement proposal to delete an asset but got an error back. Check the chaincode logs to see what the chaincode reported about the request. The peer may also log something about that specific request

Comment: @david_k there was nothing in the chaincode logs. When set to DEBUG mode on the peer, it only displays the TLS handshake was approved.

Comment: In debug mode the peer would show chaincode execution times as well as requests for proposals in general, are you sure that caliper is actually interacting with that network ?